# why opensearch in graylog netflow very hungry for disk space?

Tags: opensearch, graylog

I installed graylog+opensearch, and my disk space / 100% for 5 days(80GB). How i can free space and configure index,shards,refresh rate in config file. Btw what do mean -
"GET /_opendistro/_knn/warmup/index1,index2,index3?pretty
{
"_shards" : {
"total" : 6,
"successful" : 6,
"failed" : 0
}
}
How i can input this in CLI linux?

I tried to find information, but I don't understand how to change attributes

upd: also i can't enter in web UI grayylog- deamon not started